# What do you lose without kolmogorov extension theorem?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes

It's said that stochastic processes require the Kolmogorov extension theorem to create a joint probability space, I'm wondering what happens without it?

Why can't finite dimensional approximations be sufficient to prove most results?

Comment: Hi apart from Kolmogorov's extension theorem there is also the approach by Ionescu-Tulcea extension theoem which is more measure theoretic : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ionescu-Tulcea_theorem while Kolmogorov involves topological properties unless mistaken. regards

Comment: This post might be of interest : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/267568/kolmogorov-extension-theorem-vs-caratheodory-extension-theorem